# How to view all the work someone did

Tags: jira, attachment

I'm searching for a file a college uploaded, while that person is no longer availabe. [Apparently](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/58558/search-and-show-all-tickets-that-have-attachments) it requires a paid plugin to locate all attachments. But might it be possible to view all work/changes someone made?

Comment: You can query database directly if advance search does not bring what you want

Comment: Can't you just search for all jobs that are assigned to that user? e.g. `/browse/JOB-ID?jql=assignee%20in%20(USER-NAME)` Can be acheived by clicking issues then search issues.

Comment: @Novocaine Tried that and those tasks didn't include the file. We did end up finding the file on a task that had been taken over by someone else. Anyway, I was hoping something like this would be possible.